# Can I add an event listener to the update of a bound DataGrid in VB?

Tags: sql, datagridview, vb6

I want to log a username/date if a user updates a particular database table from a VB6 application.  I have covered most of my bases (stored procedures, insert operations, etc.) but I still have undocumented changes being made.

I think this comes from some DataGrid objects that are being updated when a user uses the Tab key.  The original purpose of this project is to allow the users to update live data by "tabbing through," and we want to keep this feature.

I cannot figure out how to add an event for when a user does this.  It appears my only remaining option is to add a DML T-SQL trigger on the specific tables.  Is there a better solution?

Comment: It's not clear what you'er asking. Do you have the source? Because if so, why don't you just put a breakpoint on the tab-through feature? OTOH then triggers, SQL Server profiler, etc would be a way forward.

Comment: After giving my question a read-over, I can see that I wasn't very clear with my question.

Comment: I'm having an issue finding (in code) of where to set a breakpoint to catch the TAB key press.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the event handlers built into DataGrid objects are declared as the following:

```
Private Sub grdDataGrid_KeyPress(KeyAscii As Integer)
Dim character

character = Chr(KeyAscii)
KeyAscii = Asc(UCase(character))

End Sub
```

I will have to make code changes to this function to say if you are tabbing through, then a procedure needs to be called to log the user's information as per the stated requirement.

Thanks to anyone who took the time out of their day to read my question.  I appreciate it! :)